# MS OFFICE excel vs Open office Calc vs libreoffice calc and same formula not working on each why Any suggestions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, interop, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

Please help me on

- MS OFFICE excel
- Open office Calc
- libreoffice calc

and the same formula is not working on each.

Why same Copy paste and formula not working on each others.

Comment: Which formula do you mean? Sure that they do not work?

Comment: @kwoxer ,formula for calucation multiple rows ....Please tell me if we do not want to use MS exel which is BEST from others .

Comment: What is the exact formula that you want to work in Excel that does not?  It is hard to give any guidance at this point.

Comment: You should post an example, else your question is too broad.

Comment: Brake it down into a small example.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

formula has been written in correct way for each type of productivity tool  and issue has been resolved .

Comment: First time I downvote an answer but this is not an answer but a joke, isn't it? "We have now done it the correct way and now it works." This answer is really the answer to **all** questions.

Comment: drop down list is not working when on excel to anther excel tab .--agents-users is facing issue  i have requested  ed  to post screenshots.